# Reftex-toc prevent vsplit on goto

Tags: emacs, latex, spacemacs, auctex

I am currently using spacemacs with auctex. When I use reftex-toc and goto an item then it performs a vsplit and shows the content in the right window. How do I prevent this splitting behaviour? I would like it to open in the current buffer from which the command was issued.

It is related to [reftex-toc.el](https://github.com/DamienCassou/RefTeX/blob/master/lisp/reftex-toc.el#L799).

I added this hook to maximize the newly opened window: 

  `(add-hook 'reftex-toc-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-maximize-buffer)`

but it is a suboptimal solution, as it influences other splits I might have made.

---

Answer (score 1):

What you describe could be related to the way you select an item.

In normal Emacs (not Spacemacs), I see that `SPC` is bound to `reftex-toc-view-line` which behaves just how you describe it. But `RET` is bound to `reftex-toc-goto-line-and-hide` which seems to do what you want.

Maybe you just need to find out where that function is on your keymap.

Comment: I have tried both SPC, RET, and TAB, which has three different behaviours. None of them do what I asked

Comment: You could try to find the keybinding of the function `reftex-toc-goto-line-and-hide` by asking Emacs. In standard Emacs that's `C-h w` which invokes the command `where-is`. Sorry, I really don't know anything about keybindings in Spacemacs.  Try the equivalent of `M-x where-is` to invoke that command explicitly. Then ask for `reftex-toc-goto-line-and-hide`.

Comment: I have no issue finding that command. But it does not do what I want. It still opens the toc item in a new window.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't understand that earlier. Then, I'm afraid I can't help you any further. It works for me on my Emacs 24.5.1 on Linux with reftex-version 24.5.1 and I don't think I fiddled around with any split/how to open buffers settings in general. You can take a look at my config at https://github.com/ska2342/ska-init-files/blob/master/dot.emacs.d/init.el if you feel adventurous. In my version of reftex the function `reftex-toc-visit-location` (which is called under the hood) is defined in reftex-toc.el and has a comment which states pretty clearly that it should hide the TOC buffer.